# systemd[1] failed to mount tmpfs at /sys/fs/cgroup no such file or directory

Tags: kernel, systemd, buildroot

I'm trying to load my custom zImage which was built with help of buildroot (using jumpnow_bbb_4_9_defconfig, jumpnow_bbb_defconfig etc...) The kernel versions that I used - 4.9.1, 4.14.96. In both cases an error occurs during boot:

```
    systemd[1] failed to mount tmpfs at /sys/fs/cgroup no such file or directory
```

my u-boot bootargs:
        console=ttyO0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait

The boarg that I'm using is PH8700 system on module(I believe the PCB design is similar to Beagle Bone Black board).

The filesystem is on emmc. zImage provided from the manufacturer loads fine. What could be the problem?

log pics:
[log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRf4Q.png)

[log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCwWQ.png)

[log3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93KBZ.png)

Comment: Did you enable cgroups in your custom kernel?

Comment: Hi) How to do that in buildroot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd uses cgroups, you need to enable them in your custom kernel. With Buildroot:

1. `make linux-menuconfig`
2. `General setup` -> `Control Group support`
3. exit saving your changes
4. `make`

Comment: Thank you for the reply!) It helped, but kernel now loads too long, some additional messages occured with [OK] prefix. The message "A start job is running for dev-mmcblk0p1.device(1min/1min 30s)" hungs for a minute. What is going on? How to avoid this? Maybe it is connected with the file system incompatability with the new zImage? I'll add log pics in thequestions.

Comment: Maybe you need more options in your kernel. Boot with the manufacturer kernel and check if you have a `/proc/config*` file (see https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system). If you have it, start from that configuration for your kernel.

Comment: Also, please don't post images. Among other issues, you can't search in an image.

Comment: Ok. In config file manufacturer uses Linux/arm 4.1.6 Kernel. Can I use this config with any kernel or I have to change some other buildoot parameters, like kernel version, source etc?

Comment: I've built the zImage using manufacturer config. The kernel doesn't print anything. Maybe I set the wrong name of console (I've tried ttyO0, ttyS0). By the way how to figure out the right name for the console?